# Excel VB - Set cell value that depends on another cell

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba

Basically I have this right now: https://i.gyazo.com/5890c00b96526f86c8bea8b5f4fe3a85.png

What I need is this:

If cell 1 = 0 then set the value of cell 2 to 10 and cell 3 to 0, if cell 1 = 1 then set the value of cell 3 to 10 and cell 2 to 0.

What I tried:

```
If cell1 = 1 Then
    cell2 = 10
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = 10
    cell2 = 0
End If
```

It works for cell2 but not for cell3. ( #VALUE! )

Any ideas please?

Comment: There's no cell3 in the code you pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming active cell as cell 1, modified your code a little, and it works as required, kindly try and let me know

```
Sub test()
'assuming activecell as cell 1

If ActiveCell.Value = 0 Then 'cell 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 10 'cell 2
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = 0 'cell 3
End If
   If ActiveCell.Value = 1 Then 'cell 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0  'cell 2
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = 10 'cell 3
End If
End Sub
```